# How do i set selected item in a dropdown PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a table `bus` with columns `bus_id, bus_no`.

I tried echo  multiple with multi selection, I tried the below code but its repeating the `bus_no`.

Please help me to echo all buses and echo `selected` beside the selected ones.

```
<form name="editstudent" method="get" action="testmulti.php">
<select name="numBus[]" multiple>

<?php
$selBus=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM najdsy_bus order by bus_id");
while ($rowBus=mysql_fetch_array($selBus)) {
    foreach ($numBus as $key=> $value) {
        if ($rowBus['bus_id']==$value) {
            $SelectedBus = "selected";
        } else {
            $SelectedBus = "";
        }
        echo '<option value="'.$rowBus['bus_id'].'"'.$SelectedBus.'>'.$rowBus['bus_no'].' '.$SelectedBus.'</option>';
    }
}
?>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="test">
</form>
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysql). If you care to learn, [here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is a quite good PDO-related tutorial.

Comment: Show an example of the output you're getting, and of the output you want.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `$rowBus[bus_no]` to `$rowBus['bus_no']` and `$rowBus[bus_id]` to `$rowBus['bus_id']`

The reason of this changes is that $rowBus is an array with structure like this `Array ([bus_id] => value)`. As you see its key is a string, so to access it you have to "tell" php to look for it.

The string can be represented in `"some_string"` or `'some_string'`. Because key is some text without any special formatting for better performance you are recommended to use `'` instead of `"`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you shouldn't put `echo '<option value="'...` inside of `foreach`. Change it to this:

```
while ($rowBus=mysql_fetch_array($selBus)) {
  $SelectedBus="";
  foreach ($numBus as $key => $value){
    if ($rowBus["bus_id"]==$value){
      $SelectedBus="selected";
    }
  }
  echo '<option value="'.$rowBus["bus_id"].'"'.$SelectedBus.'>'
     .$rowBus["bus_no"].' '.$SelectedBus.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: You should not just have `selected` though. It should be `<option value="whatever" selected="selected">something</option>`